# Short transit time in Frankfurt when traveling from UK to Austria

Tags: germany, layovers, short-connections, lufthansa

I am traveling from Glasgow, UK to Austria on a single ticket (Lufthansa) with a layover at Frankfurt airport. The plane lands and departs from Terminal 1. I have no checked luggage, only one carry-on bag, and will travel on a Sunday afternoon. I am an Australian citizen and have an Australian passport.

Will I need to go through customs and/or security screening at Frankfurt? I have a 1h transit time, and the on-time performance rating for this flight is [not great](https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-ontime-performance-rating/LH/961). How likely will the transit time cause me to miss my connecting flight?

Comment: Lufthansa must think the connection is doable or they wouldn’t be selling the ticket. Are there other LH flights to your destination that same day as a backup? Is your arrival in Austria time-critical should there be a delay?

Comment: Yes there is another flight later on, but then I will arrive in Austria around 11pm. I have never been to this Austrian city, so I'd like to arrive ~6pm.

Comment: easiest way would be to land closer to Austria, and take a train from there, or land directly in Austria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will I need to go through customs and/or security screening at Frankfurt?

Yes. I don't think you can use the automated kiosks with an Australian passport, so you probably will have to queue up. Passport controls tends to be quick, customs is basically non-existent but security can be quite slow. I don't think you will have to go through security but that depends a bit in your arrival concourse. You will almost certainly depart from concourse A.

> How likely will the transit time cause me to miss my connecting flight?

Impossible to know but Lufthansa thinks its doable, otherwise they wouldn't have sold you the ticket.

If you miss it, they will just put you on the next flight. I would probably a good idea to look up what that would be. Chances are that would delay you just by an hour or two but that depends on your exact details.